# UVa Online Judge ANSI C Runtime Error with scanf but Accepted with gets combined with sscanf

Tags: c, runtime, scanf

I will omit the whole code but these tests so far can be quite disturbing:

This get Accepted with ANSI C, C++ and C++ 11

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int p, q, r, s, t, u;
    char* str = malloc(1000);
    while(gets(str) != NULL) {
        sscanf(str, "%d %d %d %d %d %d", &p, &q, &r, &s, &t, &u);
        printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", p, q, r, s, t, u);
    }
}
```

The disturbing fact comes now, this code get Runtime Error in ANSI C but Accepted in C++ and C++ 11:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int p, q, r, s, t, u;
    //== 6 instead of != EOF also gives me a runtime error
    while(scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", &p, &q, &r, &s, &t, &u) != EOF) {
        printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", p, q, r, s, t, u);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `return 0;` - in C this means that `main()` returns a garbage status to the shell. In C++ omitting the `return 0;` is allowed, and a default status of 0 (== `EXIT_SUCCESS`) will be returned. In C however both of your programs will return an undefined status. In the first case you happen to get lucky and 0 is returned. In the second case something other than 0 is being returned (probably -1). Try and get into the habit of always returning a valid status from main regardless of whether you're working with C or C++.

See [this excellent question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204483/253056) for further details.

Note also that compiling with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) would have alerted you to this mistake immediately and saved you some time.

Comment: could you explain better, why with the gets don't returned garbage status?

Comment: Did you read the linked answer (especially the penultimate paragraph) ?

Comment: I know just fine how shell works but can't understand why it works with gets and not scanf

Comment: The return status is undefined for C in both cases - in the first case you happen to get lucky and 0 is returned. In the second case something other than 0 is being returned (probably -1). Try and get into the habit of always returning a valid status from main regardless of whether you're working with C or C++.

Comment: So probably its assembly linked and some stack position or register sticks with another value than 0 and is returned if the last command is scanf, looks great, now, add this to your answer to make it perfect, thanks, this was an eye error indeed.